# 'str' object not callable in Python Selenium library

Tags: python, selenium

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I searched through some other questions, they all said that i redefined a function earlier in my code, but i could not find any occasion where I did this.

My code is:

```
    firstElement = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="assessment-leaderboard"]/li[1]')
    print(firstElement)
    if len(firstElement) > 0:
        print(firstElement[0].text())
    else:
        print('no data')
```

Comment: please add html structure of element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the issue is that `.text` is not a function but an attribute, so you might want to try

```
print(firstElement[0].text)
```

without `()`.